# Is there any pega function that should vanish the present appearing button and shows another button?

Tags: pega

I created a pega application which contains Add to cart button, my requirement is that when I click on the Add to cart button it should vanish and it should show Remove button.

I tried by creating data transform for Remove product and gone through some commands in definition

Answer (score 0):

Buttons have visibility conditions.

One approach can be:-

On click of Add to Card, refresh the current `section` by setting one flag `property` `HideAddToCard` as true.

Apply visibility condition on that button based on the HideAddToCard property value.
If its true then hide it.

You need to set this property as false before load of the `section`. If your section is called through a flow action rule, then you can set that flag property as false in pre processing action.

Same kind of logic can be applied on Vanish button.